# Null pointer exception when login fields are empty - Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have this code where the user enters his credentials and logs in.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private TextInputEditText mLoginEmail;
private TextInputEditText mLoginPassword;

private Button mLoginBtn;
private Button mForgotPass;

private ProgressDialog mProgress;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.login_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Login");


    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);


    mLoginEmail = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.login_email);
    mLoginPassword = (TextInputEditText)findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    mLoginBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_create_btn);

    mLoginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String email = mLoginEmail.getText().toString();
            String pass = mLoginPassword.getText().toString();

            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)){

                mProgress.setTitle("Logging in");
                mProgress.setMessage("Please wait while we check your credentials");
                mProgress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                mProgress.show();

                loginUser(email,pass);

            }

        }
    });

    mForgotPass = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_forgot_password);
    mForgotPass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}

private void loginUser(final String email, final String pass) {

    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    sendToMain();
                } else {
                    mProgress.hide();

                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Can not login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(task.getException()));
                }
            }

    });
}

private void sendToMain() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(mainIntent);
    finish();
}
```

}

To achieve a login procedure I call the **signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass)** method as you see above. Just for validation purposes I want to have a toast saying that you should fill both email and password fields. As it is now, I get an exception when I click the login button. How to fix that?

This is the exception.

```
 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbq.zzgm(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Unknown Source)
    at theo.tziomakas.news.LoginActivity.loginUser(LoginActivity.java:90)
    at theo.tziomakas.news.LoginActivity.access$300(LoginActivity.java:22)
    at theo.tziomakas.news.LoginActivity$1.onClick(LoginActivity.java:70)
```

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: On your if you should add an else when fields are empty and show your toast there.

Comment: @PmanAce. In which if? I put a Toast after the if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass)) but get the same exception.

Comment: @@PmanAce. It is not an easy task. I don't know why I go a down mark.

Comment: Look at my answer. You got a down vote because you didn't show your error probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your error, the following:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
```

should be an && and not a ||:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
```

You want both to be not null to call your login.